# Selector + Transition combination doesn't work well in Android 4.2

Tags: android

I have an app with the following requirement

1. Under normal situation, background of list view row needs to be in **white**.
2. When being selected, the background of list view row needs to be in **blue**.
3. Perform animation on 2 list view rows, to make them transit from **red** to **white**.

It seems that I can make use of selector and transition to solve this kind of problem.

### linear_layout_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/linear_layout_transition" />
</selector>
```

### linear_layout_transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red" />
</transition>
```

### simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_selector"
/>
```

### Java code to perform animation

```
{
    // Animate 1st row.
    View view0 = this.getListView().getChildAt(0);
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = (StateListDrawable)view0.getBackground();    
    Drawable currentDrawable = stateListDrawable.getCurrent();
    if (currentDrawable instanceof TransitionDrawable) {
        final TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = (TransitionDrawable) currentDrawable;
        transitionDrawable.resetTransition();
        transitionDrawable.startTransition(0);
        transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(1000);
    } else {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "WTF! 1st currentDrawable is " + currentDrawable);
    }
}
{
    // Animate 3rd row.
    View view2 = this.getListView().getChildAt(2);
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = (StateListDrawable)view2.getBackground();    
    Drawable currentDrawable = stateListDrawable.getCurrent();
    if (currentDrawable instanceof TransitionDrawable) {
        final TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = (TransitionDrawable) currentDrawable;
        transitionDrawable.resetTransition();
        transitionDrawable.startTransition(0);
        transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(1000);
    } else {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "WTF! 3rd currentDrawable is " + currentDrawable);
    }
}
```

***All things works expected as in Android 4.1 and Android 2.3.3***

However, when comes to Android 4.2, things broken. The following was observed under normal situation.

[image]

1. Under normal situation, starting from 2nd row, all rows became red.
2. Under normal situation, 1st row's background still remain as `TransitionDrawable`. However, 2nd row and subsequent rows's background **had mystery became others**. This can be seen from log

> WTF! 3rd currentDrawable is
>   android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@b3068498

The complete project to demostrate this problem can be downloded from here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbalqjzzw5tu7e9/transition_bug.zip

I was wondering, is this a bug? Why a `TransitionDrawable` can become `LayerDrawable`? Is there any workaround to overcome this?

### Note

The problem will gone, if I apply `linear_layout_transition` directly as TextView's background. However, I will lost the feature provided by selector.

Comment: I guess you filed a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54784

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in JellyBean. `Resources#getDrawable(int)` will return the correct type (`TransitionDrawable`) on the first request, but will return the wrong type on any consecutive requests (in this case `LayerDrawable`).

I noticed the same happens when cloning the `Drawable` as follows (I was trying to cache & re-use the `Drawable` myself).

```
Drawable clonedDrawable = backgroundDrawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();
convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(clonedDrawable);
```

You can overcome this issue by setting the selector to your ListView (`ListView#setSelector(int)`) and setting the `TransitionDrawable` as a background to your list-item (`convertView`).